# MethodAccessException was unhandled

Tags: c#, wpf

ok I have a WPF program that works on one computer but not the another. on the other one, I get this MethodAccessException was unhandled

it is when the problem calls NotifyPropertyChanged():

```
public abstract class NotifyChanged: INotifyPropertyChanged {

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    /// <summary>
    /// PropertyChanged can be triggered whenever a Property changes value.
    /// It is also available for classes which inherit from 
    MachineComponent.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// NotifyPropertyChanged can be called explicitly, by sending the name 
     of the property as a string,
    /// or implicitly, by calling it without parameters from the Property 
    that changes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info"></param>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Design", 
   "CA1026:DefaultParametersShouldNotBeUsed" )]
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string info = "none passed" ) {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null ) {
            PropertyChanged( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( info ) );
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

anyone know why ?

I am told this code come from a Microsoft site

Update.. I am adding the full error message. now this is a run time error message

full error message:

```
System.MethodAccessException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233072
 Message=Attempt by method 
'Moxtek.XRF.Core.LocationViewModel.set_LocationName(System.String)' to 
 access method 
 'Moxtek.Common.Abstract.NotifyChanged.NotifyPropertyChanged(System.String)' 
  failed.
  Source=Moxtek.XRF.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Moxtek.XRF.Core.LocationViewModel.set_LocationName(String value) in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.Core\ViewModels\MeasurementRecipeViewModels\LocationViewModel.cs:line 41
   at Moxtek.XRF.Core.LocationViewModel..ctor(XrfLocationSet location, LocationItemViewModel locationItem, MeasurementRecipeItemViewModel recipeItem, IDataObject`1 locationData, IServiceLocator services) in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.Core\ViewModels\MeasurementRecipeViewModels\LocationViewModel.cs:line 12
   at Moxtek.XRF.Core.LocationItemViewModel.GetItems() in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.Core\ViewModels\MeasurementRecipeViewModels\LocationItemViewModel.cs:line 36
   at Moxtek.XRF.Core.LocationItemViewModel..ctor(IDataObject`1 locationData, MeasurementRecipeItemViewModel recipeItem, IServiceLocator services) in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.Core\ViewModels\MeasurementRecipeViewModels\LocationItemViewModel.cs:line 14
   at Moxtek.XRF.Core.XrfViewModel..ctor(ChartingViewModel chart, IServiceLocator services) in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.Core\ViewModels\XrfViewModel.cs:line 29
   at Moxtek.XRF.WPF.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in C:\Users\lolsen\Source\XRF\Moxtek.XRF.WPF\App.xaml.cs:line 46
   at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Moxtek.XRF.WPF.App.Main()
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
   InnerException:
```

Comment: full error msg plz. including call stack and line

Comment: Tends to be caused by copying an older version of the DLL onto the machine, one where the member was still private.  Look at source control for recent changes.

Comment: Are both computers running the same version of .NET Framework?

Comment: CallerMemberName attribute is a .NET 4.5 feature, so if running on an older framework it doesn't work.

Comment: Tom Farley they are both running  the same Framework. 4.6.1

Comment: Steve, I did added the full error message

Comment: To me it looks like you are calling code from a class library but the version of the class library in the directory of your executable does not match the latest compiled version of the library (i.e. outdated dependency). May that be the case?

Comment: Anpep, the code was written by someone else, but we are told this is the latest .dll file for this projects.